# About the critical points of quasi-convex functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

What do we know about the structure of critical points of quasi-convex functions?

---

I am looking for statements like "the critical points of a quasi-convex function are always either a global minima or a saddle point" or "for a quasi-convex function the number of negative eigenvalues of its Hessian at a critical point is constant across intervals of values of the function evaluated at the critical points"

Are statements like this known?

Answer (score 2):

A local minimum of a quasi-convex function is a global minimum.  At a critical point where the function is $C^2$, the Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite;  if such a  critical point is not a local minimum, the Hessian matrix must be singular there.  An example of this is the function $f(x) = x^3$.

Comment: Any reference for this?